# Getting album data from callback in Spotify App

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm building a Spotify app, and want to have featured albums. My JSON data specifies albums, so I loop through them with a simple `for` loop. However, unlike track data, which is directly available via `track.data.album.name`, album data needs to be extracted via callback:

```
var a = models.Album.fromURI(appData.Albums[i].uri, function(album) {
        console.log("Album data: ", album.name);
});
```

This works as expected, with the console showing the album names, but I can't find any examples of how you would make that data available outside the callback function. `a.uri` seems to be the only thing that works:

```
var a = models.Album.fromURI(appData.Albums[i].uri, function(album) {
    //console.log("Album data: ", album.name);
});
console.log("Album data: ", a.uri);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm a little confused if this is a Spotify App issue, or if I should be using closures or anonymous functions inside the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you get back from `models.Album.fromURI()` is be the same object that's passed to you in the callback:

```
var a = models.Album.fromURI("spotify:album:1KtFTJnuQbMDpKJRHQonYZ", function(album) {
    console.log(a === album);
    // ^Logs "true"
});
```

The `uri` property is available immediately since it's already known — you give the URI to the object to start with. The rest of the metadata is loaded asynchronously, and will be available in the original `a` object once the callback has been fired. In the callback you may want to call another function that actually updates your URI or whatever you need to do next.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I think my problem is not understanding how to fire the callback inside the loop properly - for that I think need a closure. But your answer cleared things up perfectly.

Comment: Yep, that's what was happening - `models.Album.fromURI()` needed to be called by a closure. A modified version of the 2nd code example here worked great: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures